# How to use a for loop to console log each item of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, ecmascript-6

I'm working on an assignment that experiments with different types of loops. I have to use a for loop to `console.log` each item in the array `cars`. I can only use a `for` loop, no other methods such as `for each`. What am I missing?

I have tried console logging `cars` but that logs the entire array a number of times equal to the number of strings in the array, which is obviously not correct. I'm also fairly certain that the `.length` method used in the `for` loop is incorrect as well.

```js
const cars = ["ford", "chevrolet", "dodge", "mazda", "fiat"];
for (let i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
  console.log(cars)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the above code, you need to log `cars[i]` to the console:

```js
const cars = ["ford", "chevrolet", "dodge", "mazda", "fiat"];
for (let i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
  console.log(cars[i])
}
```

`cars` is the array, and to access one item in the array, you need to use the numerical index (in this case `i`).

You can also eliminate indexes entirely by using a `forEach` loop, which is often simpler and faster than a traditional `for` loop:

```js
const cars = ["ford", "chevrolet", "dodge", "mazda", "fiat"];
cars.forEach(car => console.log(car));
```

Comment: Ah! So much simpler than I had thought. Thank you for the help!

Comment: No problem @Jim.

Answer (score 1):

`cars` refers to the entire array. What you want is to access an item in the array by index in the for loop: that can be done by using `cars[i]`:

```js
const cars = ["ford", "chevrolet", "dodge", "mazda", "fiat"];
for (let i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
  console.log(cars[i]);
}
```

Even better: you an [use `forEach` instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), which is way more readable:

```js
const cars = ["ford", "chevrolet", "dodge", "mazda", "fiat"];
cars.forEach(car => {
  console.log(car);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use foreach too

```js
const cars = ["ford", "chevrolet", "dodge", "mazda", "fiat"];
cars.forEach(function(element, index) {
  console.log(element, index);
});
```